# Executing serverside code from javaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Not sure if this is possible or not, but here's my scenario:

In about 10 of our aspx files we have the same javaScript function, I want remove this from all these pages and put it in the main javaScript file (main.js) which is global to all pages, so it's easier to maintain. the javaScript code in the current aspx pages looks something like this:

```
var regEx_gaid = <%= regEx["regEx_gaid"] %>; 
var regEx_wCard = <%= regEx["regEx_wildCard"] %>; 
var regEx_fCss = <%= regEx["regEx_flattenCss"] %>; 
var regEx_iCss = <%= regEx["regEx_inlineCss"] %>;
...

function doSomething() {
   // do something with those variables declared above.
}
```

Not sure how to get the server side values for those variables in main.js.

also this may also be relevant:

"regEx" inside `<%= regEx["regEx_gaid"] %>` is a dictionary collection on the server side and "regEx_gain" is key to access the value of the regEx dictionary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a separate ASP page which just outputs the content of your variables.  Then you can make an AJAX request to that page from javascript.

using JQuery for shorthand:

```
var regEx_gaid = "";

$.get('regex_gaid.aspx', function(data) {
  regEx_gaid = data;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this solution, and I just tried it and it works, but I am still curious to see if it's possible to do without creating an extra aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

In your pages, you can create these javascript vars dynamically in each page by using [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx):

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MainVars", "var regEx_gaid = '" + regex_gaid.ClientID + "';", true);
```

We use this mechanism extensively: register the control variables in code-behind (they are emitted into each page), but then consume them in a central script (similar to your main.js).

Comment: I modifed my question but regEx inside <%= regEx["regEx_gaid"] %> is a dictionary collection on the server side and "regEx_gain" is key to access the value of the regEx dictionary.

Comment: It should be the same concept: if you are already pulling it into js using the syntax you are showing, then you just modify the script that I had shown. If this is the first time that you are trying to send the dictionary to the client, the you most likely need to create a json structure from it on the server and assign it to that variable in the startup script (we also do this).

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a `main.js.aspx` then move the scripts in `main.js` to `main.js.aspx`, and use main.js.aspx as a javascript file?

main.js.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="main.aspx.cs" Inherits="TempProject.js.main" %>
var regEx_gaid = <%= regEx["regEx_gaid"] %>; 
var regEx_wCard = <%= regEx["regEx_wildCard"] %>; 
var regEx_fCss = <%= regEx["regEx_flattenCss"] %>; 
var regEx_iCss = <%= regEx["regEx_inlineCss"] %>;
```

CodeBehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
    }
```

Other files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js.aspx"></script>
```

Comment: The main aspx page is accessed by the entire application, doesn't seem very optimized to have that code show up on all the pages.

Comment: I mean to add a new `main.js.aspx`, and use it as a js file.

Comment: ahh gotcha, yeah that will work too, though I still will have to go to all those pages and reference the new file.